# close any running application through another application programatically

Tags: blackberry

Can we close any other applicaton running in background from our application.
Want functionality just similar to Task manager.
Is it possible? Any hint.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Victim" application should implement GlobalEventListener, and "killer" application should send a global event for the "victim" application. When "victim" app receives the specific event it closes.

If you want to close not your application, there is no way to do that. It just does not know that you want to close it.

Comment: I don't want to close my application.

Comment: Do u have any sample how to does it?

Comment: I do not have sample code, but you can find it via google. Search for BlackBerry GlobalEventListener. And note that you cannot close another application if it "does not know" that.